# Package name of stock SMS-app on Galaxy S2/S3/S4?

Tags: android, sms, galaxy

What is the package name of the factory-default SMS/MMS ("Messaging") app on the Galaxy S2/S3/S4? It's not using the stock Android app, correct?

Comment: Write an app that lists all the packages on the device and make a guess.  It will probably have SEC (Sony Electronics Corp) in it.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have access to any of the mentioned devices at the moment, but thanks for your comment, Gabe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are rooted you may want to try using Root Explorer you may want to go /system/app/SecMms.apk open it up and check the `manifest.xml` and you'll find the package name is : `com.android.mms` P.S this is the actual package name from the stock message app in S4.

Comment: Thanks, k0sh! I don't have access to an S2/S3/S4 right now, so this was very helpful, thank you :-)!